# Unable to understand Tkinter configure

Tags: python, tkinter

I am reading a script about how to make a small game of dice rolling, and now have a difficulty understanding the last two lines below:

To me, it seems the image was already updated by ".configure(image = DiceImage)"

So why we have to update the image again by the last line "ImageLabel.image = DiceImage"?

```
ImageLabel = tkinter.Label(root, image = DiceImage)

def rolling_dice():
    DiceImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(random.choice(dice)))
    ImageLabel.configure(image = DiceImage)
    ImageLabel.image = DiceImage
```

Comment: You are not updating it again, you are simply storing it because if you didn't it would be automatically cleaned from memory. You don't have to store it like that, you could make it global, or add it to a list, or a dozen other ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `ImageLabel.image = DiceImage` is not configuring the widget. Tkinter images get destroyed by the garbage collector if a reference isn't saved somewhere. This results in a blank space where the image should be.

Saving it as an attribute to the widget it is associated with is the simplest solution to work around that problem.